# C# DataAdapter, DataTable -> not updating back to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, dataadapter

I wrote a simple test to check my dataAdapter code. I connect to the SQL Server database, fill a datatable, change a value in a row, and call `da.Update(table)` to send the changes back to SQL Server. The table has a primary key. Not at all sure why this isn't working...(see code)

```
connectionToSQL = new SqlConnection(SQLConnString);
connectionToSQL.Open();

var wktbl = new DataTable();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TAGS$",connectionToSQL);                 
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(wktbl);

wktbl.Rows[3][2] = "5";
wktbl.AcceptChanges();

da.Update(wktbl);
```

Comment: You can not update like that. Here after filling the values in the datatable, what ever the changes you do for datatable will purely relates only to it. And you again have to write some query to update similarly for selecting. And call ExecuteNonQuery() to execute the Update.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UpdatetableusingSqlDataAdapter.htm

Comment: @skk: The `SqlDataAdapter` builds the UPDATE query automatically, and `da.Fill` should then use that to update the database. @user1051076 It's probably  the call to `AcceptChanges` that breaks this, since it resets all the rowstates to unchanged...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just skip the call to [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx) and the code should work fine. It marks all rows as unmodified so there's nothing left to do for your Update call.

Comment: i agree with Damir. You would generally call AcceptChanges *after* performing the update.

Comment: @MoeSisko: You don't need to call `AcceptChanges` at all, since `Update` does that too.

Comment: Ah, yes removing the accept changes worked.  Thanks for info around the "modified state".  this is actually a test for code that could not get to work previously, so I will work on that and see if I need some more help.

Comment: Okay, I would like to expand my question to my original effort...I select * from an Excel spreadsheet into dt.  I want to take those values and update the SQL table.  (the SQL table exists because of a manual import to SQL from the original Excel spreadsheet, has a primary key set, user updates the excel sheet, I need to update the SQL values.)  I am setting the RowState to modified in an effort to invoke the Update.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I would like to expand my question to my original effort...I select * from an Excel spreadsheet into dt.  I want to take those values and update the SQL table.  (the SQL table exists because of a manual import to SQL from the original Excel spreadsheet, has a primary key set, user updates the excel sheet, I need to update the SQL values.)  I am setting the RowState to modified in an effort to invoke the Update.

connectionToSQL = new SqlConnection(SQLConnString);
                connectionToSQL.Open();

```
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TAGS$",connectionToSQL);                 
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var b = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            //dt.Rows[3][2] = "20";

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                r.SetModified();
            }

            da.Update(dt);
```

Comment: "I would like to expand my question to my original effort". If you want to change your question you should edit your question or ask a new one. You added an answer and won't be received as you intended.

Comment: Glad I could help. I saw that you added the new question. You should probably delete this answer.